# Dynamically get blob contents when a new folder gets created in the storage account container using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm using an Azure Logic App to get Blob contents from my Storage Account. My storage account has a container with 2 subdirectories. Eg. Container > Pics > 202001 > Pic1.png
The second sub-directory will change every month. (eg. 202002, 202003)
So I need to dynamically get all the contents from the new sub-directory created, without manually having to enter the path of the newly created folder in my logic app designer.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subdirectories are very regular, so easy to do, you only need to use time-related functions.

Your container path can be written like this:

```
/gong/test1/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMM')}/
```

[image]

I did a test and it seems to trigger correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Frank! 
If my sub-directory looks like this -->  " 20200901 "  (yyyy-mm-dd)
How shall I add my function?

Comment: It is in this form: `/gong/test1/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd')}/`. You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions).

Comment: Thanks Frank! I'll work around this. This helped ofcourse! Thanks again mate!